# Rails - attr_accessible & mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mass-assignment

I have a question about using `attr_accessible` in Rails.

I sometimes want to set `guard_protected_attributes` to `false` in order to bypass mass assignment protection. I'm wondering why the following line doesn't work (it creates the "can't stringify keys" error):

```
@user.attributes=({ :name => "James Bond", :admin => true }, false)
```

...but this does:

```
@user.send(:attributes=, { :name => "James Bond", :admin => true }, false)
```

Anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the Ruby parser parses '`{ :name => "James Bond", :admin => true}, false`' as the *single* argument to `#attributes=`. Calling a method '`foo=`' limits you to one argument in Ruby. The `send` gets around that.

What's actually happening is that Rails is trying to stringify the keys of `false`, which, being a `FalseClass` rather than a `Hash`, doesn't have any.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me crazy!

Comment: I actually ran some tests in IRB. The single argument is an Array, which also can't stringify its keys.

Comment: Just once I'd like to see an array stringify its keys.

Comment: OK, Dave: Array.class_eval { def stringify_keys; result = {}; each_with_index { |x,i| reuslt["#{i}"] = x }; result }.  But I personally don't have a use for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to see if you guys would follow up this, so I have to use .send or if there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I wound up just defining some helper methods to make bypassing the mass assignment restrictions a bit easier.

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base

    # Assigns attributes while ignoring mass assignment protection
    def force_feed(attributes)
      self.send(:attributes=, attributes, false)
      self
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of ActiveRecord the second parameter to attributes= was taken out. You can now call with the same effect:

```
model.assign_attributes(attributes, :without_protection => true)
```